# DNN how to inject JavaScript code in all pages in between <head> tags

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am trying to insert a piece of JavaScript code in all my pages at once if that's possible.  I'm hoping this is possible but I've yet to encounter how to do it.  The code needs to go in between the     tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In DNN9 (perhaps earlier versions) on the Site Settings page there's a HTML Page Header Tags setting in which you can add whatever you like.

[image]

You could also do it through code, in your SKIN, or by creating a Module that you put on every page.

```
RegisterScript(Page page, string filePath, FileOrder.Js priority) // default provider, uses fileorder enumeration
```

Documentation is at

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/client-resource-management-api

When all else fails, add it to the default.aspx file, but if you do that, know that when you upgrade DNN, you'll lose those changes.

Comment: Thank you sir. I appreciate the help.  I was wondering if I was able to do that through the Module Settings, then Advanced settings where it gives the option to add the module to every page.  Now I know!

Comment: You cannot do that through the module settings unfortunately, unless you create a custom module that does this, and then include that on every page through those settings.

Comment: it is possible to add html module and set to show on all pages , it is good if you don`t want to execute js on specific page, just remove module on that